# Registration page with UI dialog and showing information on <p> element

Tags: jquery, dialog, registration

I need to make a registration page on HTML, on which the user must registrate before he/she can use the webpage. When the page opens, there is nothing else except "Registration"-button, and when that is clicked the user is asked about name and username by jQuery UI dialog.

If the user entered both values and the length of each value field data is at least 5 characters, the data is right and dialog can be closed by "Save"-button. Dialog can be also closed by "Cancel"-button, which does not store information. If data was wrong, the dialog can not be closed and the user is shown some kind of error message.

When registration succeeded, the dialog is closed and the user is shown the content of the webpage below the dialog. On the upper part of the web page is shown the information of the registrated user on `p`  element.

So...

1.How could I transfer/show succesfully the information of a registered user on the top of the web/HTML page?

Here is my code so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var dialog, form,

      // From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
      //emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      name = $( "#name" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "The form information " + n + " has to have a length " + " between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function addUser() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 5, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

      if ( valid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Save": addUser,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addUser();
    });

    $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });


  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="information"></p>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Registration">
  <p class="validateTips">Give name and username</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" placeholder="name">
      <label for="password">Username</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" placeholder="username">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Registrate</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know that anyone can turn off Javascript in browser, or toggle your hidden elements in developer's tool? That is why we do not do registration and such authentication on client side. You should use some server side code to do this.

Comment: Ok, but this code is about practising use of Jquery etc., not code for an actual public web page yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the opening table tag.

Change the following code:

```
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
    <thead>
    </thead>
```

Into the following (adding the missing table tag with ID "users".

```
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
   <table id="users">
    <thead>
    </thead>
```